# Material Components theme dialog buttons go puffy after changing theme of Application

Tags: android, material-components-android

Today I was trying out new material components part of their instalation is that you need to change parent of your app to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents.
So I did it because I wanted to use Bottom navigation with nicer ripple. But after that, almost all buttons in application got puffier.

What should I do to revert to the previous state (image on right)?

[image: On left is a material version on right is appcompat version]
On left is a material version on right is appcompat version

Answer (score 13, accepted):

During research, I found the answer I will leave it here maybe it will help someone.

Reason that they look like this is because they use `style="attr/buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle"` and Material theme overrides them

To fix this problem you need to use Bridge theme instead of `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light`

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

more here: 
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes

Comment: This helped me, but there is no real explanation why. Also there is an open bug in google's issue tracker for that (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116861837), so it seems to be a bug.

Comment: This works but using the bridge also removes the ripple effect on the buttons when using a TextButton, not sure how I could fix that though!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to use [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog) from the AndroidX AppCompat library:

```java
AlertDialog signInDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
        // TODO: Add your code here
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
        // TODO: Add your code here
    })
signInDialog.show();
```

Note: If you're using the [Material Components for Android library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and/or you're using the new `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` themes, you should instead use the [`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` class](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md), which should be used in place of the AppCompat `AlertDialog` class as described below:

> Material maintains usage of the framework `AlertDialog`, but provides a new builder, `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`, which configures the instantiated AlertDialog with Material specs and theming.

Here's an example (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this).apply {
    setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?")
    setPositiveButton("OK") {
        TODO("Unimplemented functionality")
    }
    setNegativeButton("Cancel") {
        TODO("Unimplemented functionality")
    }
}.show()
```

Comment: no, its not working with 'Theme.MaterialComponents.Light'

Comment: @arsalanelec You should use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` class from the Material Components library: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md

Answer (score 1):

`Solution`

Stop use of `android.app.AlertDialog` and replace with  `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog` it will solve your problem

`You can use`

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
    </style>

    or

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    </style>
```

But it will cause you when you will use the material component like `ExtendedFloatingActionButton`, `MaterialButton`, etc