# DatePickerDialog and Theme.MaterialComponents

Tags: android, themes, material-design, datepickerdialog

I have two themes `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`, and `Theme.MaterialComponents`. My date picker dialog is looking as expected for the first theme but for the dark theme, it shows a white background. Any ideas to make it look as expected??

1. [My datepicker in Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAdGe.png)
2. [Date picker in Theme.MaterialComponents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwqcb.png)

Expected : I want a dark background in the second image

Comment: Three questions: 1. are you using the constructor parameter (`DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents`) to define this choice of theme? 2. which version of the material and appcompat libraries are you using? 3. what are `colorPrimary`, `colorSecondary`, `colorSurface` etc in the activity theme?

Comment: 1) Am not sending any parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in this answer [Material Components theme dialog buttons go puffy after changing theme of Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293029/material-components-theme-dialog-buttons-go-puffy-after-changing-theme-of-applic)

I used Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge instead of Theme.MaterialComponents as parent in my dark theme.